# Encrypting and decrypting strings

Tags: c#, vb6, encryption

Does anyone know of a good way to encrypt and decrypt strings using VB6 to ensure sensitive data is secure?

Also, is there an encryption method that can be shared between VB6 and .NET?
Example:

The encrypted string will be written to a database using a VB6 application, but the value also need to be read an decrypted in a c# .net application using the .net framework if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question has a fundamental flaw in reasonsing: **encryption does not ensure that sensitive data is secure**. Encryption ensures that sensitive data is **encrypted**. Secure data and encrypted data are *not* the same thing, no more than a locked car is a secure car. Locked cars get stolen, broken into, blown up, or smashed on the freeway every day. To ensure that the data is *secure* the first thing you have to do is *work out what all the threats to the user are*, and then mitigate them one by one; odds are very good that only a small number of the threats will be mitigated by encryption.

Comment: "Locked cars get... smashed on the freeway every day" WTF?@! This guy is simply asking for AES here :-))

Comment: @wqw: my point is that locking a car does not protect it from many forms of accidental or deliberate damage. *Locking data with encryption does not protect it from accidental or deliberate damage either*. If the goal is to keep the user's data *secure* then you've got to state a *threat* that you're securing it against. Most threats are *not* mitigated by encryption; if the actual threat is one of those then encryption is making the the situation *worse*, not *better*.

Comment: This is a rather cynical reasoning and the ultimate conclusion being that there is no such thing as "secure car". Purely theoretically secure car must be Lim[locked->inf](car) and this of course has no practical benefit to the OP, besides being educational :-))

Comment: Thanks for your comments Eric, but the main part of my question that I am concerned about is where I can bet perform the same encryption methods used by two different applications written in different languages.  I am not asking if encrypted and secure data are the same.

Comment: @wqw: of course there is no such thing as a "secure car", any more than there is a "tastier soda". *Tastier than what?* "Tastier soda" doesn't *mean* anything if you don't state what it is tastier than. "secure car" doesn't mean anything either *until you state what threats the car is secured against*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at System.Security.Cryptography?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx

I would look at the AesCryptoServiceProvider.

Comment: +1. I suggest writing a C# component that exposes the .Net crypto stuff to the VB6. Like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719105(VS.71).aspx

Comment: I'm accepting this answer based on the comment from MarkJ.  Building a .net component that can be wrapped by COM and made usable by VB6 ensures that the same code is being used by both applications.  Thanks to everyone for all of your input.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than putting the work of encrypting / decrypting on the application side, perhaps you could handle the security in the database using the Cryptographic Functions of Transact-SQL?  After all, both applications would be connecting to the same database.

Comment: This sounds easiest, although you need to assess whether the DBA will be able to decrypt the passwords, and if this is a risk or not.  Sometimes you put the encryption in the application rather than the DB to separate the information that the DBA has access to.

Comment: You also need to make sure the DB driver encrypts traffic (or use a private interface).

Comment: This is a great idea. Unfortunately the version of the database I am using does not support the Cryptographic function in T-SQL.

Comment: @dretzlaff17 - what database are you using?  SQL Server 2000?

Comment: Yes, I am using SQL Server 2000 - MSDE

Comment: You'll probably want to look into Extended Stored Procedures.  This reads like a pretty clear explanation: [here](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/SQL-Server/Extended-Stored-Procedures-Intro-And-10-Cool-Examples/) and some code for traditional encryption (AES, Blowfish, etc) [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Security/freeencryption/1980/) and [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Security/sql2000dbatoolkitpart1/2361/).

Answer (score 1):

My first thoughts would be to use the built-in CryptoAPI which is built-in to the Microsoft operating systems.  This would give you the common-ground effect between your VB6 and C# development platforms.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_API

Some quick & dirty sample code here: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=804

And this is one of the many sites explaining how to do this in C#:  [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alejacma/pinvoking-cryptoapi-in-net-c-version)

Comment: Eeek!  -1 but no comments... why the hate?  :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I'm voting you up one for taking the time to provide me information as a possible solution to my problem. I am not sure why someone would vote this down with no reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

You could try VBCorLib which supports the same cryptography classes as found in .NET. The crypto classes in VBCorLib provide a nearly identical API as the .NET classes, so the code will be very similar to perform encryption/decryption between the two platforms.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/vbcorlib/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, [symmetric encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) algorithms such as [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) are pretty standard so as long as you are using the same keys for [encryption](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2389) and [decryption](http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx) there should be absolutely no problem.